# How 꽃차례 is pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

How 꽃차례 is pronounced? Kkot-charye or kkoch-charye? For example, 있다 is pronounced "itta", but 있습니다 isn't pronounced "itseumnida".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Naver dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/6616b0bdf27b43ae9b99b677c8d41c3c) it is pronounced as 꼳차례

꽃-차례 -次例
Pronunciation [ 꼳차례 ]

있습니다 is not pronounced itseumnida because ㅆ 받침 followed by ㅅ is always pronounced as ㅆ.

Answer (score 1):

꽃차례 is pronounced as 꼳차례 /k͈o̞t̚t͡ɕʰa̠ɾje̞/. Some pronounce it *incorrectly* as 꼳차레 /k͈o̞t̚t͡ɕʰa̠ɾe̞/ as it is quite difficult to pronounce 례.

**Note 1**: You should avoid romanizations because they do not reflect 경음화 (fortification) at all. For example, the romanization of 국가 is gukga but the pronunciation of 국가 is 국까 /kuk̚k͈a̠/.

**Note 2**: 있다 is pronounced as [읻따](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=117415) /it̚t͈a̠/ (Some pronounce it *incorrectly (for convenience)* as 이따 /it͈a̠/); 있습니다 as [읻씀니다](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=*216*&qna_seq=143438) /it̚s͈ɯmnida̠/ (Some pronounce it *incorrectly (for convenience)* as 이씀니다 /is͈ɯmnida̠/).

Comment: I have never heart 있습니다 as 읻씀니다, although some sources provide it as correct pronunciation.

Comment: Unless the official rules reflect the reality, 읻씀니다 is the correct pronunciation. More than 80% of people omit ㄷ when they pronounce ㄷㅆ of 읻씀니다 (reference: 표준 발음법 영향 평가), which seems to be one reason you have never heard 읻씀니다. Another reason could be that 있읍니다 had been the correct spelling until 1988. It has been about 30 years since 있습니다 became the standard. I wish the national institute would add exceptions to the rules.